# Cannot call apex rest service from jquery on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, jquery, apexrest, cross-domain

I'm new to rest services in Salesforce.  I've defined the following rest service in Apex:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mediaPlanDetail')
global with sharing class MediaPlanDetailService {

    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet() {

        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;    
        response.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        response.addHeader('content-Type', 'application/json');

        String URL = 'http://services.somecompany.com/services/loadByMediaPlanId';

        String payloadStr = '';
        System.debug(RestContext.request.requestBody);

        String rows = RestContext.request.params.get('rows');  System.debug('rows = ' + rows);
        String page = RestContext.request.params.get('page');  System.debug('page = ' + page);
        String sidx = RestContext.request.params.get('sidx');  System.debug('sidx = ' + sidx);
        String sord = RestContext.request.params.get('sord');  System.debug('sord = ' + sord);
        String mediaPlanId = RestContext.request.params.get('mediaPlanId');
        String pageSize = RestContext.request.params.get('pageSize');

        String finalUrl = URL + 
                '?rows=' + rows +
                '&page=' + page + 
                '&sidx=' + sidx + 
                '&sord=' + sord + 
                '&mediaPlanId=' + mediaPlanId +
                '&pageSize=' + pageSize +
                ''
                ;

        Http objhttp = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setMethod('GET');

        req.setEndpoint(finalUrl);

        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('Accept-Language', 'en-US');
        req.setTimeout(120000);

        try {
            res = objhttp.send(req);

            if(res.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase('OK') && res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // Logic to parse the response
                String body = res.getBody();
                system.debug('-------- HttpResponse received: ' + body);

                final String PAYLOAD_ELEMENT = '\"payload\":';
                final String EXCEPTION_ELEMENT = '\"exception\":';

                integer payloadPos = body.indexOf(PAYLOAD_ELEMENT); System.debug('payloadPos = ' + payloadPos);
                integer exceptionPos = body.indexOf(EXCEPTION_ELEMENT); System.debug('exceptionPos = ' + exceptionPos);

                payloadStr = body.substring(payloadPos + PAYLOAD_ELEMENT.length(), exceptionPos - 1);

            }

        }
        catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        }

        return payloadStr;
    }

}
```

I'm calling this service using a jQuery plugin call jqGrid.  Here's a snippet of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var mpId = $.urlParam('mediaPlanId');

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail',  // this fails with 302 Found
    //url: 'https://somecompany--cpq.cs7.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail',  // this fails with 401 not authorized
    postData: {
        mediaPlanId: mpId,
        pageSize: 10
    },
    loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        //jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'OAuth ' + __sfdcSessionId);
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');
        //jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}');
    },
```

The VF page where I'm calling the service has this location:

```
https://somecompany--cpq--c.cs7.visual.force.com/apex/jqgrid_test_page?mediaPlanId=2271
```

When I call the service using

```
/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail
```

the service returns a 302 with an alternative Location in the header:

```
https://somecompany--cpq.cs7.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/mediaPlanDetail?mediaPlanId=2271&pageSize
=10&_search=false&nd=1437743215834&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

When I use the redirected location as the URL, I get a 401 Unauthorized response with Cross-Origin Request Blocked messages in my browser.

In either case, my Apex rest service is never called.  I see nothing in the Debug Logs indicating that my browser is actually calling it.

This looks like a classic cross domain scripting issue between the Salesforce VP page domain and the domain used for Apex rest services.  I spent a lot of time yesterday reading various posts on both calling SF rest services and cross domain issues, but wasn't able to find a solution.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search return pretty helpful results:

**Code:**

```
function CallRestAPI()
{
var weblink = "http://URL";

$.ajax(
{
url : weblink,
type : 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function (request)
{
request.setRequestHeader("HeaderName", "HeaderValue");
},
crossDomain: true,
success : function(result)
{
    //process the result
},
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('Error: '+jqXHR.status);
alert('ErrorThrown: '+errorThrown)
} 
}); 
}
```

**LINK**

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AtOIAU

I would think the JS removing would be a MUCH better case, call the remote method and have that method call the web service directly.

Comment: I tried adding j$.ajaxSetup({crossDomain:true}); and j$.ajax({crossDomain:true}); to my page.  I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known behavior of Apex REST services that calls from the VF domain are not considered safe in the same origin policy.

To work around this the forcetk library from the [force.com Javascript REST toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) will allow you to make such calls via a proxy.

Although, I'm not sure that is necessary in this instance. You could, instead, use the @RemoteAction Apex annotation instead. Unless you're finding the request size is too big or something.

Comment: I'm not having any luck getting forcetk to work.  I'll post a new question on that.  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/cannot-call-apex-rest-service-from-jquery-on-visualforce-page
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sessionId = '00AAA000000BBBB!YYYY_ZZZZ_.VVV_WWW.PPP_QQQ_RRR.SSS';
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'https://csMM.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/NNN/updateLLL',
            data: `{
                "request": [
                    {
                        "action": "FFF",
                        "startDate": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "moreParameters": "..."
                    }
                ]
            }`,
            processData: false,
            // "For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything
            // other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
            // text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request
            // to the server"
            // On the other hand, sending Content-Type: text/plain... meets HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
            // The best match for JSON worked with the OPTIONS preflight
            // request (but required sending a text in data with processData set
            // to false).
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",

            // The response comes with "Content-Type: application/octetstream" as a JSON text.
            dataType: "json",
            jsonp: false,

            // The "withCredentials" flag causes Firefox refuse sending the
            // POST after OPTIONS because Salesforce declares "do not send cookies
            // in your data requests" with the following response header,
            //  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false.
            //
            // On the other hand Salesforce's OPTION response also has
            //  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-SFDC-Request-Id,authorization,content-type
            // which seems sufficient for Firefox to proceed with POST after commenting out
            // withCredentials.
            // xhrFields: {
            //     withCredentials: true
            // },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionId
            }
        }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            // To let the browser access the returned data, add the
            // URL of the site hosting this HTML page in
            //   https://csMM.salesforce.com
            // under Setup / Quick Find / CORS / New.
            $('#output').text(data.field1.subfield2[0]);
        }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            $('#error').text(textStatus);
        })
    })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, world.
        <p>
        Output:
        <span id="output"></span>
        <p>
        Error:
        <span id="error"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```